# Is it considered bad practice to create instances using the New keyword inside a library when using an IOC Container?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Please see the code below:

```
public class EnquiryFactory : IEnquiryFactory
    {
        public Enquiry Create(string firstName,string surname)
        {
            return new Enquiry(firstName,surname);
        }
    }
```

The Castle Windsor configuration looks like this:

```
container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For<IEnquiryFactory>().ImplementedBy<EnquiryFactory>());
```

Is it considered bad practice to create instances using the New keyword inside a library when using an IOC Container? Should I be generating replacing this:

```
return new Enquiry(firstName,surname);
```

to something like this:

```
return container.resolve<Enquiry>(firstName,surname);
```

I have looked into the AsFactory facility: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md, however I believe this is only used to create dependencies after an object is created.

Comment: IMO, this doesn’t seem like it is ALWAYS bad but rather it depends on factors like how likely is it that the concrete type getting instantiated might change in the future or if injection would serve an obvious advantage (eg. injecting a different concrete type for testing).

Comment: Prevent constructing your components (Enquiry) using [runtime data](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). That would remove the need to have [a factory](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100) as well.

Comment: @Steven, are you saying that factories should only be used to create new objects (with default values) ?

Comment: Factories that create services are not always a bad thing, but quite often a better solution is one without a factory.

Comment: @Steven, could you have a look at my question here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991017/understanding-the-command-pattern-in-a-ddd-context.  It is about one of your articles and follows from this question.

Answer (score 1):

As blins already commented it depends whether it's an issue that your application is coupled to Enquiry class. In your case it seems that Enquiry is just a DTO object with no behaviour, so in this case it wouldn't cause any trouble.
But anyway as creating of Enquiry is already abstracted behind factory, you are always able to bring new implementations. Just like:

```
public class ExtendedEnquiryFactory : IEnquiryFactory
{
    public Enquiry Create(string firstName,string surname)
    {
        return new ExtendedEnquiry(firstName,surname);
    }
}

public class ExtendedEnquiry : Enquiry
{
}
```

And register your new factory instead the old one:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IEnquiryFactory>().ImplementedBy<ExtendedEnquiryFactory>())
```

Comment: Enquiry contains behaviour.  Would I use Asfactory?

Comment: As I said your solution is already sufficient, but by registering typed factory by AsFactory you would avoid the need to create your own factory class (having IEnquiryFactory is enough for Castle). So in theory both approaches are equivalent, but with AsFactory you will end up with less code, because Castle will take a care about Enquiry creating. (you must also register Enquiry in your container)

Comment: I believe the benefit of asfactory could present itself if the enquiry constructor changed.  Do you agree?

Comment: Is there a way of creating a manual factory and then asking castle to return the type without using the service locator pattern?

Comment: Yes, if constructor changes, than castle factory is beneficial.

Comment: Can you answer the question in my last comment.  I should then be able to mark the answer.  Also I assume that asfactory is not an example of the service locater pattern?

Comment: There is one more way by registering delegates. See: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.cz/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-1.html

Comment: No asfactory is not an example of Service locator. It's just a factory that returns instance of specific class. Client code which uses this factory can get just Enquiry from that, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I almost forgot about this question.  Do you have an example, which shows how to configure a factory interface in Windsor, which accepts primitive types? +1.

Comment: @w0051977 It' quite easy.  If you register your interface (having method `Enquiry Create(string firstName,string surname)`) like `AsFactory`, than Castle will pass these primitive type parameters to `Enquiry` constructor based on their names.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it acceptable to do this in the Domain Layer bearing in mind that the Domain Layer should not be dependant on anything.

Comment: Your factory registration is done in your composition root, which is not a part of your domain layer, and your domain layer being dependent on factory interface is ok, because it is just an interface and your domain layer doesn't know what is behind.