# Understanding the Command pattern in a DDD context

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I was recently reading this article here: https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100.  It appears to talk about using commands (http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern) instead of application services.

Please see the code below:

```
public sealed class ShipmentController
{
    private readonly ICommandDispatcher dispatcher;

    public void ShipOrder(ShipOrder cmd) => dispatcher.Dispatch(cmd);
}

sealed class CommandDispatcher : ICommandDispatcher
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public void Dispatch(dynamic cmd) => GetHandler(cmd.GetType()).Handle(cmd);

    private dynamic GetHandler(Type type) =>
        container.GetInstance(typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(type));
}
```

which replaces code like this: http://www.zankavtaskin.com/2013/11/applied-domain-driven-design-ddd-part-6.html

I have three questions:

1) Is this saying that you should have one command per command request in the Application Service Layer? Wouldn't this result in class explosion e.g. if you have 100 commands?

2) What do you do with CQRS queries? Do you create regular application services for these?

3) What do you do with scenarios where you extract from the database (say an order); perform a command on the Order e.g. CalculateTax and then persist to the database? I assume the flow would be (is this right):

```
MVC 
Application Service (to extract order from database)
Command (Application Service calls CalculateTaxCommand)
```

Comment: 1) No. Http request and `command request` are two completely different things. And yes, for `command request` you would have at least 3 classes: `command`, `handler` and `response`.
2) No. You have the same principle as `command`s, except queries are idempotent (they can't modify anything). This means you might need to encapsulate your db access so that nobody can write a query that modifies something
3) You would: a) send a query b) execute a command to `calculatetax` c) execute a command to update the db

Comment: @zaitsman, can you confirm that each query/command is encapsulated in its own class?

Comment: This is a theory :) So yes, it should be as that is the only thing that guarantees the separation level. The whole point of DDD and CQRS is that it allows to decompose your application down to a few lines of isolated code, which is a lot easier to refactor in a team of 20+ devs and across thousands of operations.

Normally all commands, queries and handlers inherit some interface or a base class. Also check out MediatR (https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR)

Comment: Is this a c# question only?

Comment: @zaitsman Idempotent doesn't mean they can't modify anything, it means that a function can be executed multiple times but the result won't change after the first execution.

Comment: @DavidG Good point. For OP: query can not modify `state`. Whatever state your application is concerned with should be modified through `command`.

Comment: @zaitsman, I found this example here: http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2016/08/19/DDD-Application-Services-Explained.  What is the response (as in command, handler, response) in this case? Thanks.

Comment: `IDomainServices` would be split into 2 commands.

Comment: @zaitsman Do you mean immutable rather than idempotent?

Comment: @DavidG I don't like the sound of `immutable` :) I was trying to re-phrase the classic definition by Martin Fowler: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html

Comment: Would ICommandResultMediator  be the response?

Comment: @zaitsman Oh, then idempotent is absolutely not the word you want to use.

Comment: @w0051977 maybe. That interface is obscure altogether. Typically you would use normal POCOs as response to allow you to serialize your CQRS classes and thus decouple parts of your app on different computers

Comment: @zaitsman, do you know of any "good" examples that demonstrate what you are trying to say?

Comment: @w0051977 MediatR - the link i posted in my second comment :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> It appears to talk about using commands instead of application services.

No, it does not talk about the command design pattern. There is a very clear, and crucial distinction between the [Command design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), and the CQRS-like patterns.

The 'command' in the Command design pattern combines both *data* and *behavior* within the same class. With CQRS, on the other hand, the command is simply a message, a data container, with no behavior. Behavior is moved to a 'handler' class. The handler is identical to your old 'application services' with the distinction that a handler has a very narrowly defined scope. This separation is the driver that enables the maintainability and flexibility of this design.

> 1. Is this saying that you should have one command per command request in the Application Service Layer?

The simple answer is: Yes. Although I rather talk in terminology of use cases, rather than requests. You should define one command and command handler per use case. If users of your application can decide to cancel their order, you would get one `CancelOrder` message that gets handled by the `CancelOrderHandler` service. The use case to change the shipping address, would lead to the introduction of a `ChangeChippingAddress` message with a companion `ChangeChippingAddressHandler` service.

> Wouldn't this result in class explosion e.g. if you have 100 commands?

It is a very common misconception to think there is a direct reverse relationship between the number of types in a system and its maintainability; an increase in classes would means a decrease of maintainability.

The [SOLID design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), however, favor small and focused classes over big classes, because making classes smaller, can actually increase the maintainability of a system tremendously.

This is exactly what's going on here. This design should be viewed from the point of SOLID. My experience is that, within the systems I refactored to that model, we saw a massive increase in maintainability of an order of a magnitude, even though the amount of classes could as well increase with an order of a magnitude.

> ***TIP:** Do not worry about the number of classes in your system. Just worry about maintainability.*

This doesn't mean that project structure is irrelevant, though—it certainly is relevant. You should find a good project structure for your commands, their handlers, and their decorators. In [the comments](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-query-side-of-my-architecture/#steven---23-october-15) of [this blog post](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-query-side-of-my-architecture/) there are some ideas of how to structure your project.

> 2. What do you do with CQRS queries? Do you create regular application services for these?

I do exactly the same to queries as I do to commands. Each query should have its own query message and a handler, and optionally a result message class. [This blog post](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2011/meanwhile-on-the-query-side-of-my-architecture/) describes how to design you queries.

> 3. What do you do with scenarios where you extract from the database (say an order); perform a command on the Order e.g. `CalculateTax` and then persist to the database? I assume the flow would be (is this right):

This is an atomic operation and should all be part of the command. When the command is executed, the order is loaded from the database, based on its ID captured in the command. The tax is calculated and the order is persisted as part of that (business) transaction.

In chapter 10 of [my book](https://cuttingedge.it/book) I go into a lot more detail than I can provide here. I discuss how these patterns relate to SOLID and AOP and go through a step-by-step refactoring as an example, and demonstrate the power of decorators.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer.  +1.  Is Mediatr (referenced by zaitsman in the comments under my OP) used by the command design pattern or the CQRS command?

Comment: MediatR is absolutely a form of the CQRS architectural style of design and it is an interesting source to learn from and use it as inspiration for your own design.

Comment: Is this CQRS pattern documented "formally" anywhere? I realise you and Jimmy Bogard (two blogs I regularly read) have referred to it, however I wandered where it originated from.

Comment: For simplicity sake, I refer to this pattern as 'CQRS', but it isn't. It is related to CQRS, since it is similar to the design Greg Young used when defining CQRS, but they are different because you can do CQRS without this design.

Comment: There are several places you can go to. For instance, chapter 10 of my [upcoming book about DI](https://manning.com/seemann2) describes it from perspective of SOLID. The book will likely be published in Q2 of 2018, but if you purchase it now, you can download the first 8 chapters. I'm expecting the publisher to release chapter 10 in a month or so.

Comment: There is also an amazing [PluralSight course about CQRS and distributes systems design](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/cqrs-theory-practice) that you should watch, but note that this particular design that Jimmy and I talk about itself is AFAIK not mentioned in that course (which proves they are two different things).

Comment: Thanks.  I will take a look.  Could you have a look at my CQRS type question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363001/separating-the-domain-model-from-the-data-model.  What is your opinion of having a data model and a domain model i.e. the ORM is mapped to the data model and the domain model is completely isolated?

Comment: Having a data model seems to contradict what this author suggests: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/04/05/having-the-domain-model-separate-from-the-persistence-model/.  He advises mapping NHibernate to the domain model, however if I did this I would have to unseal my classes; make my properties virtual; introduce parameterless constructors etc (as he advises).

Comment: I have no strong opinions on both. I've used both methods depending on the project.

Comment: thanks.  Can you describe the circumstances that made a separate data model suitable in your experience?

Comment: If you want to apply DDD (which implies a complex domain), you _need_ a separate data model, because ORMs are _always_ too limiting. Another reason to have a separate data model is to keep your domain truly decoupled from ORM and data access, which is important for some projects.

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing? What is your opinion of creating a generic value object like this: https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/blob/master/DddInPractice.Logic/Common/ValueObject.cs i.e. all DDD value objects inherit from it.  A Value Object is a DDD concept rather than a concept in the ubiquitious language of my domain.  p.s. I am going to check out your course over the next few days.

Comment: That generic value obkevg2is a smart solution tp work around C# limitations. You might want to try specifying your domain objects in F# instead.

Comment: Btw, the course is not mine, but by Michael Perry. The book is mine though.

Comment: What does obkevg2i mean? What is the C# limitation you are referring to? I will check out the book as well.

Comment: All that abstract base class does is to enable compare-by-value semantics, because C# does not generate this code for us. F# on the other hsnd does, and its syntax is the closest you can get to a definition of your domain that is exact _and_ readable by your domain ecpert. Your F# code for your domain (you can keep all other application logic in C#) can become documentation: executable documentation. You should give it a try.

Comment: thanks again.  Do support the use of a value type superclass? What do you mean by obkevg2i? I will check out F#.

Comment: That's a typo. Replace with "object is".

Comment: If you have a collection/array as a property, then it fails.  Is that right?  Also isn't it considered a bad idea to have class names that aren't in the Ubiquities language? This really is the last question.

Comment: I think that base class implementation is very simplistic, it indeed fails with collections. About class names, I don't think it is that much of a problen to have a ValueObject base class though.

Comment: Is there a better implementation anywhere? The generic base class here appears to be the same as the problematic one: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/06/25/generic-value-object-equality/

Comment: Don't know. I've got little experience with that. Again: take a look at F#.

Comment: do you have any posts in your blog, which talk about CQRS and validation? I am trying to decide whether to validate in the controller and/or Command class and/or Domain Model.  An example of validation includes ensuring surname contains a value.  By the way I find your blog very useful.

Comment: I don't have written anything in particular about validation of commands on my blog. There are many ways to do this, but I typically start with using DataAnnotation attributes in my command and implement a decorator that kicks off validation of a command before it reaches the handler. For more complex validation, define a separate `IValidator<T>` interface so you can have validator implementations for specific commands. The decorator can kick off validation of these validators as well.

Comment: thank you.  What about the Domain Model.  Do you duplicate any validation there?

Comment: You should not duplicate validation.

Comment: Do you know of any examples e.g. on GitHub where this approach is used?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: Do you have any superficial validation in the domain model at all? I assume you are doing this: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/04/29/validation-inside-or-outside-entities/

Comment: Although not specific to validation, you might find the [following discussion](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices/issues/4) about authorization useful, and it might give you some ideas on doing validation as well.

Comment: That link was useful thanks.  Do you do any superficial validation in the domain model if you are using commands and doing superficial validation in the commands?

Comment: My domain models are typically Anemic. My commands are my verbs. Validation can be done at several levels. On the command using attributes, on special IValidator<T> implementations on the command (both executing before invoking the handler), or even using IBusinessRule<TEntity> implementations that run just before comitting the transaction (and thus, after the handler ran).

Comment: i have asked a follow on question here:https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348337/how-exactly-should-a-cqrs-command-be-validated-and-transformed-to-a-domain-objec.  I would be grateful for your comments/answer If you wish.  I realise you typically use anemic domain models, however I read one of your blog posts earlier about command objects and validation, so I thought I would ask.  Thanks.